# Parsing File I/O

Tags: c++, file-io, io

I writing a C++ program that needs to be able to read from a .txt file, and parse the input in order to be able to get commands and arguments from each line.

Say I have Animals.txt

```
A cat1 3
A dog1 4
A cat2 1
D cat1
```

I want to be able to take this file, and then create a set of if statements for the first letter, so that I can call a function in the main class that corresponds to the first letter, and pass the rest of the line in as arguments.

An exmaple of what i'm trying to do:

```
if(line[0].compare("A")==0){
    add(line[1],line[2]);
}
if(line[0].compare("D")==0){
    delete(line[1])
}
```

I've tried to use strtok and the stringstream classes, but either I dont know how to implement the for my needs or they do not work for my needs as values are being put in line[0] that are not at the beginning of the lines of the text file.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Um, you don't know how to **use** them for your needs. You aren't going to **implement** them; they're already there.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem?  I think you'll need to post more of what you've already got coded and running to get any useful feedback.

Comment: Also, you can't name a function `delete`; that's a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

First you need `std::ifstream` to open the file. Then you need `std::getline` to extract lines from the file:

```
std::ifstream file("Animals.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
  // ...
}
```

Then inside the while loop, stick the line in a `std::stringstream` and extract the values you need:

```
std::stringstream ss(line);
char letter;
ss >> letter;
// And so on...
```

For a `char` you can do simple `==` comparison in your `if` statements:

```
if (letter == 'A') {
  // ...
}
```

If you extract the letter into a `std::string`, just make sure you compare against `"A"`.

I'll let you plug it all together and figure out the rest.

Comment: This is really helpful, but I have implemented something similar and  kept running into problems due to the fact that lines can have a different number of arguments depending on the first char. Do I solve this by having the stringstream nested in the if statements? any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: @user2073188 Have the `std::stringstream` outside the `if` statements and read the first character. Then, within your `if` statements, extract more content from the `std::stringsteam` as required. For example, if you get `A`, do `ss >> some_string >> some_int;`. If you get `D`, just do `ss >> some_string;`.

Comment: stringstream seems like overkill for this situation, he doesn't appear to need to know where linebreaks are

Comment: @MooingDuck Sure, they could do without it. I like to do it because it separates the extraction of a line from the file and the parsing of that line. Of course, if the line breaks aren't guaranteed to be there, I wouldn't do it like this.

Comment: @sftrabbit: [yeah but, it's SOO easy! :(](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e07f9d25431c445468da0ded69aab248)

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly! I had something similar but it wasn't working until you made it clear to me how stringstream could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `istringstream` object to split each line:

```
std::istringstream line(my_line);
std::string line0;
std::string line1;
std::string line2;

line >> token;
if (line0 == "A") {
    line >> line1 >> line2;
    add(line1, line2);
} else if (line0 == "D") {
    line >> line1;
    remove(line1);
}
```